# Query regarding identifying the different type of devices

Tags: java, http

I have a  query regarding the HTTP request.If i have one server side service which caters requests from different types of devices.How can i know from the HTTP request(user-agent) what type of device (android,IOS) is sending the request.

Thanks in advance.
Learner.

Answer (score 0):

The user agent String will contain Strings such as `iPhone`, `Android`, etc...

You can search for such Strings in the user agent using, for example, `userAgent.contains("Android")`.

Here are some sample user agent Strings :

For Android :

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; **Android** 4.0.4; Galaxy Nexus Build/IMM76B) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.133 Mobile Safari/535.19

For iPhone :

> Mozilla/5.0(**iPhone**;U;CPUiPhoneOS4_0likeMacOSX;en-us)AppleWebKit/532.9(KHTML,likeGecko)Version/4.0.5Mobile/8A293Safari/6531.22.7

For iPad :

> Mozilla/5.0 (**iPad**; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25

Comment: for IOS devices do i need to check individually for Iphone/IPAD devices.

Comment: @Learner If you want to identify iPad devices, you have to search specifically for "iPad". You can easily find in Google examples to all kinds of user agent strings.